# Akka HTTP - How to get the raw (not URL decoded) request URL?

Tags: http, http-headers, akka, akka-http

I am using Akka HTTP and having the following HTTP request:

```
http://www.example.com?p1=1&p2=2&p3=http://www.example.net?a=1&b=2%203
```

Is there a way in Akka HTTP to get the full raw (not URL decoded) request URL? I would like to get the full raw request URL as it is

```
http://www.example.com?p1=1&p2=2&p3=http://www.example.net?a=1&b=2%203
```

parse it and get everything after "p3=".

Answer (score 2):

Turn on the `akka.http.server.raw-request-uri-header` configuration setting, and the raw request URI will be included as the value for a header named `Raw-Request-URI`.

In other words, in your `application.conf`, set the following:

```
akka.http.server.raw-request-uri-header = on
```

Then obtain the raw request URI from the `Raw-Request-URI` header.

From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.10/scala/http/common/uri-model.html#obtaining-the-raw-request-uri):

> Sometimes it may be needed to obtain the “raw” value of an incoming URI, without applying any escaping or parsing to it. While this use case is rare, it comes up every once in a while. It is possible to obtain the “raw” request URI in Akka HTTP Server side by turning on the `akka.http.server.raw-request-uri-header` flag. When enabled, a `Raw-Request-URI` header will be added to each request. This header will hold the original raw request’s URI that was used. For an example check the reference configuration.